# La consulta espera el parametro @Nombre que no se ha proporcionado

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

```
public bool IngresarUsuario(Prueba objeto)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = Conexion.Conectar("cadenaCon"))
    {

        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            query = ("insert into Pruebas (Id,Nombre,Componente)values (@Id,@Nombre,@Componente)");
            comando = new SqlCommand(query);
            comando.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comando.Connection = cn;
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", objeto.Id);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", objeto.Nombre);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Componente", objeto.Componente);
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(comando.ExecuteNonQuery()))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        finally { cn.Close(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, ¿puedes incluir el error exacto con el stack trace completo?

Comment: if (Convert.ToBoolean(comando.ExecuteNonQuery())) aqui me sale el error y dice asi: La consulta con parámetros '(@Id int,@Nombre nvarchar(4000),@Componente nvarchar(4000))inser' espera el parámetro '@Nombre', que no se ha proporcionado.

Comment: Hola, cuando pones la conexión dentro de un bloque using ya no necesitas de `cn.Close` ya que al salir del bloque end using se encarga de cerrar la conexión.

Comment: Debes de validar los controles donde ingresas los datos, si estan vacios o si son del tipo de dato indicado.

Answer (score 3):

Este error sucede cuando el valor que le pasas a `SqlCommand.AddWithValue()` es `null`.

En este caso, `objeto.Nombre` debe estar a `null`, y tal vez eso no era tu intención. Asegúrate de que `objeto.Nombre` tenga un valor válido.

Ahora bien, si tu intención realmente es de insertar nulo para `@Nombre` cuando `objeto.Nombre` es `null`, entonces esto se puede lograr así:

```
comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", (object)objeto.Nombre ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que ocupes la siguiente manera :

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Pruebas (Id,Nombre,Componente) VALUES (@Id,@Nombre,@Componente);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query , cn);
command.Parameters.Add("@Nombre", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
command.Parameters["@Nombre"].Value = objecto.Nombre;
command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
command.Parameters["@Id"].Value = objecto.Id;
command.Parameters.Add("@Componente", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
command.Parameters["@Componente"].Value = objecto.Componente;
cn.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```